# JDA send notification to private channels

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want to have an ability to send notification to private channels of all users in my group
This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {          
    final JDA bot =
                new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT)
                        .setToken("secret")
                        .addEventListener(new DemoApplication())
                        .build();
}

@Override
public void onPrivateMessageReceived(final PrivateMessageReceivedEvent event) {
    if (event.getAuthor().isBot()) {
        return;
    }
    event.getJDA().getGuilds().get(0).getMembers().forEach(user->user.getUser().openPrivateChannel().queue());
    event.getJDA().getPrivateChannels().forEach(privateChannel -> privateChannel.sendMessage("ZDAROVA").queue());
}
```

But only sender of this private message receive a message . What did i miss ?
I use JDA with version **3.8.3_462**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes use of async operations. An async task is one that is started on another thread and possibly happens at a later time.

Discord has rate-limits which have to be respected by the operating client. For this reason and the reason that HTTP requests take some time, the requests happen in the background. The method you're using which is called `queue()` simply puts the request on a queue that is drained by a worker thread.

`openPrivateChannel()` returns `RestAction<PrivateChannel>` which means it will receive a private channel instance as a response. This response can be interacted with by using the callback parameter of `queue(Consumer<PrivateChannel> callback)`.

```
static void sendMessage(User user, String content) {
    user.openPrivateChannel().queue(channel -> { // this is a lambda expression
        // the channel is the successful response
        channel.sendMessage(content).queue();
    });
}

guild.getMembers().stream()
    .map(Member::getUser)
    .forEach(user -> sendMessage(user, "ZDAROVA"));
```

More information on `RestAction` is available in the [JDA Wiki](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7%29-Using-RestAction) and [Documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html).